# how to implement a favorite list from recyclerview's checked items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` with 2 `Fragments`. First fragment shows all items and the second fragment shows only favorite items. In each `Fragment` i've realized `recyclerview` with a list of items and each item has a chechbox. when user checks the checkbox in the FirstFragment the choosen item must be added to the favorite list that stands in the SecondFragment. The problem is i don't understand where should i have to implement a clickListener of the checkBox item? i mean i have already do this:

my custom adapter where i set a listener to the checkBox:

```
    @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Card card = cardList.get(position);

    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(holder.imageView.getResources().getDrawable(card.getImage()));
    holder.textViewHeading.setText(card.getHeading());
    holder.textViewDescription.setText(card.getDescription());
    holder.checkBox.setChecked(card.isEnabled());
    holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean b) {

                card.setEnabled(b);
               //here probably something gets wrong because 
               //by logic here i want to set to the card 
               //that item is favorite

        }
    });
}
```

But it steel not working.

and updating data in my fragment that shows all favorite items:

```
private void initTabs() {

    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);


    //set fragments
    adapter.addFragments(new FragmentOne(), "Chosen");
    adapter.addFragments(new FragmentTwo(), "List");
    adapter.addFragments(new FragmentThree(), "Three");

    //adapter setup
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position == 0){
                DataUtil.refreshChosenList();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
}
```

my entity Card :

```
public class Card {

private int id;
private String heading, description;
private int image;
private boolean isEnabled;


public Card(int id, String heading, String description, int image, boolean isEnabled) {
    this.id = id;
    this.heading = heading;
    this.description = description;
    this.image = image;
    this.isEnabled = isEnabled;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getHeading() {
    return heading;
}

public void setHeading(String heading) {
    this.heading = heading;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public int getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(int image) {
    this.image = image;
}

public boolean isEnabled() {
    return isEnabled;
}

public void setEnabled(boolean bol){
    this.isEnabled = bol;
}
```

}

Comment: do you have data binding? if not then you have to notify the `Chosen Items` `recyclerViewer` to refresh the list, if you have adapter in the recyclerViewer you can call 
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: i have tried but it is not working